# global offset table structure

Tags: linux, compiler-construction, kernel, elf

How does structure of global offset table(ELF) look. I am trying to understand dynamic linking. Can any one tell how got data structure looks. I somehow never found it online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is OS and platform-specific, but for x86/x64 Linux, the Global Offset Table is just a bunch of function addresses. There's one entry for each symbol in it. Before symbols are resolved, the addresses (for functions) point back into the Procedure Linkage Table (PLT), but are then updated to point to the actual function locations.

Comment: how can you see where are they allocated? Can I read them with HEX editor? thanks.

Comment: you can read it from a debugger, with an hex editor I think you will read all zeros since is at runtime that is filled with real data.